# Showing attributes of a object in a view with django

Tags: python, django

I'm using `Django 1.9`. I want to show a view that contains the attributes of an specific vehicle saved in the database. But when I try to access to the view, I receive an `Attribute error` instead of the list of characteristics of the vehicle. What should I correct for displaying well my view for each vehicle? Each vehicle has an `ID` and I only have a vehicle in my DB (so I put the id of that vehicle in my URL). Thanks in advance

```
views.py
===========================
    def getAuto(request, idAuto):
        auto = Auto.objects.get(idAuto=idAuto)
        ctx = {"auto": auto}
        return render('vehiculo_especifico.html', ctx)


urls.py
==========================
    url(r'^verAuto/(?P<idAuto>\d+)/$', views.verAuto),  


models.py
==========================
    class Auto(models.Model):
        idAuto = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
        Marca = models.CharField(max_length=45)
        Modelo = models.CharField(max_length=45)
        VarianteModelo = models.CharField(max_length=45)
        Ano = models.IntegerField(null=False, default=2016)
        etc..

Traceback (IOError):
=========================
Traceback:

File "C:\Users\User\Envs\vehilometro\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  149.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\User\Envs\vehilometro\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  147.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\User\Envs\vehilometro\vehilometro\vehiapp\views.py" in verAuto
  88.     return render('vehiculo_especifico.html', ctx)

File "C:\Users\User\Envs\vehilometro\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py" in render
  67.             template_name, context, request=request, using=using)

File "C:\Users\User\Envs\vehilometro\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py" in render_to_string
  96.             template = get_template(template_name, using=using)

File "C:\Users\User\Envs\vehilometro\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py" in get_template
  32.                 return engine.get_template(template_name, dirs)

File "C:\Users\User\Envs\vehilometro\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py" in get_template
  40.             return Template(self.engine.get_template(template_name, dirs), self)

File "C:\Users\User\Envs\vehilometro\lib\site-packages\django\template\engine.py" in get_template
  190.         template, origin = self.find_template(template_name, dirs)

File "C:\Users\User\Envs\vehilometro\lib\site-packages\django\template\engine.py" in find_template
  157.                         name, template_dirs=dirs, skip=skip,

File "C:\Users\User\Envs\vehilometro\lib\site-packages\django\template\loaders\base.py" in get_template
  40.                 contents = self.get_contents(origin)

File "C:\Users\User\Envs\vehilometro\lib\site-packages\django\template\loaders\filesystem.py" in get_contents
  24.             with io.open(origin.name,  encoding=self.engine.file_charset) as fp:

Exception Type: IOError at /verAuto/1/
Exception Value: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: u"C:\\vehiapp\\Templates\\{'auto': <Auto: Nissan 370z Touring AT>}"
```

Comment: Can you include your full traceback? It should point to the offending statement

Comment: Your view is called `getAuto`, but in urls you refer to it as `verAuto`, which would lead to the reported error because the `views` module has no attribute `verAuto`

Comment: Corrected some things, but now I get an IOError. I'll post traceback now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^getAuto/(?P<idAuto>\d+)/$', views.verAuto),
```

**views.py**

```
def verAuto(request, idAuto):
    auto = Auto.objects.get(idAuto=idAuto)
    ctx = {
    "auto":auto
    }
    return render(request,'vehiculo_especifico.html', ctx)
```

**vehiculo_especifico.html**

```
...
Marca: {{auto.Marca}}
Modelo: {{auto.Modelo}}
...
```

read about PEP (Style Guide for Python Code)
https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: I did it and now it shows an IOError, I'll post the traceback now, thanks anyway

Comment: render need the request object. `render(request,'template.html',ctx)`

Comment: Thank you so much! I knew that I forgot something